# Implementing Google Places API into Google Sheets to autocomplete [City, State]

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet with a column for location (city, state) and was wondering if there was anyway to implement Google Place API to make predictions based off user's input to autocomplete the city, state. If there is an alternative way to do this, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an in-cell dropdown list following the Google official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[This is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UtQ-9gzLtH2AyQqQdNPOB6TmsgEa7LVXI2136WAL-rE/edit?usp=sharing) I did and can work for you.

Comment: I've tried that, but as we type in cities from all over the US, the long list of cities makes the data validation slow and freeze at times in the sheet.